# Filtring PCollection based on values from another PCollection in python dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have two P-Collection like below

> P1 = ['1','2','4','5','6','7','8']
>
> P2 = [('1',(2,1,2)), ('5', (1,0,9)), ('9', (1,2,3)), ('10', (1,0,0)),
>   ('1',(1,1,1))]

I want to write Combiner using dataflow python so that my P2 will be filtered like below

> Result = [('1',(2,1,2)), ('5', (1,0,9)),('1',(1,1,1))]

what will be the optimized and fast way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there a set of methods that you are thinking of!

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible way of solving this:

```
def extract_keys(row):
    for e in row[1]['p2']:
        yield (row[0], e)

p = beam.Pipeline(options=beam.pipeline.StandardOptions())
p1 = p | 'p1' >> beam.Create([[str(i), 1] for i in range(8)])
p2 = p | 'p2' >> beam.Create([('1',(2,1,2)), ('5', (1,0,9)), ('9', (1,2,3)), ('10', (1,0,0)), ('1',(1,1,1))])
p3 = ({'p1': p1, 'p2': p2} 
       |'Group all keys' >> beam.CoGroupByKey()
       | 'Filter' >> beam.Filter(lambda x: (len(x[1]['p2']) > 0 and len(x[1]['p1']) > 0))
       | 'Extract keys' >> beam.FlatMap(lambda x: extract_keys(x))
       | 'Save results' >>  beam.io.WriteToText('result.csv'))
```

Which results:

```
('1', (2, 1, 2))
('1', (1, 1, 1))
('5', (1, 0, 9))
```

What is happening here: first notice that I had to use a slightly different input from yours. My `P1` is like `[['1', 1], ['2', 1]...]`. This is so we can use it in the [`CoGroupByKey`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/util.py#L64) operation that blends PCollections into one using the keys as reference for the merging (notice that the PCollections are inside of a `dict` in this step as this is the expected input by `CoGroupByKey`).

After that is done then we just filter out keys that didn't have any match. The `extract_keys` is applied just to get the expected output you are looking for.

I recommend playing around with those steps, you can for instance remove some steps in `p3` and see results for each operation to see how data is being transformed. Also, [these snippets](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/0.6.0/_modules/apache_beam/examples/snippets/snippets.html) might give you some ideas as well on how these transformations work.